# Android drag and return to previous activity like Facebook and Google Photos

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-gesture, google-photos

I have been finding a way to implement animation like Facebook and Google Photos. When in 2nd Activity, when dragging images the images follow and the 2nd Activity started to fade out and we see 1st Activity. Images of what I was trying to ask is here.
[image]

Comment: Hey..Can you give me your mail id so that i can share demo with you..May be it will help you..!!

Comment: @AndiGeeky can you please also share the demo with me?

Comment: @vipul_asri : I want to do the same so i need your mail id so that i can share because demo is on my google drive so..!!

Comment: @AndiGeeky my mail id is vipulasri.2007@gmail.com. Thank you so much

Comment: @vipul_asri : Shared..Welcome..!!

Comment: https://github.com/Commit451/ElasticDragDismissLayout

Comment: Can you please share the code to my email id perepamanohar@gmail.com @AndiGeeky

Answer (score 3):

I have found some code from Nick Butcher sample code.

[ElasticDragDismissFrameLayout.java](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid/blob/6aef263c259d25b02a7bea72dd00b5f66be5fc55/core/src/main/java/io/plaidapp/core/ui/widget/ElasticDragDismissFrameLayout.java)

and when using it:

```
chromeFader = new ElasticDragDismissFrameLayout.SystemChromeFader(getWindow()) {
        @Override
        public void onDragDismissed() {
            finishAfterTransition();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

Was you able to find a full fledged solution for this ?

https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid , It might give clues to entry transition and how that was accomplished . So it might help you there. But how about when you want to drag and dismiss that activity?

https://github.com/Commit451/ElasticDragDismissLayout , Its an interesting library. Does do drags . But doesn't remember the position where the thumbnail where it was launched from. Only handles 1 swipe direction and dismisses by sliding to the right. So its not that close to what they do in 2017 Jun Google Photos Android application. You might have to modify it.

If anyone knows a better solution to this please do share.